# certbot-auto renew command not found

Tags: amazon-ec2, certificate, certbot, auto-renewable

certbot was installed and version is 0.32.0. It was working fine, but certificate is expired recently. I want to renew it by using this command

```
certbot-auto renew
```

but got command not found issue. Tried 'sudo', same problem.

Any idea on the root cause?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For the auto renew to work, you need to add this renew command to [crontab](https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

To edit the crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

This will open a file with crontab configurations.

To configure the cron to execute this command every 12 hours, add the following line:

```
0 */12 * * * root certbot -q renew --nginx
```

To know how to configure a different time to run the command, check the [crontab references](https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

Comment: Hey @Eric. Post your solution here to other people to know how to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

For auto renew certbot certificate, the following command working with me.

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

You can check [certbot instructions](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-nginx).